# SQL Server - SELECT on DateTime

Tags: sql-server

This is a very simple task, but I cannot seem to execute the SELECT correctly

```
[Date]
2014-10-02 00:00:00.000
2014-10-02 16:54:00.000

SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE Date NOT LIKE '% 00:00:00.000'
```

Returns with both dates. how do I exclude the dates with a time value of `00:00:00.000`?

Comment: What version for SQL Server are you using?

Comment: The space character is the issue

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE CAST(Date AS time) NOT LIKE '%00:00:00.000'
```

Comment: **1.** Wouldn't you ideally convert straight to `VARCHAR` instead of to `TIME` (which then requires another implicit cast for the `LIKE` pattern-matching)? **2.** If you *do* cast to `TIME`, do you still need the `%` in the pattern?

Comment: indeed using quotes is like casting to string

Comment: Good answers accompany code samples with an explanation for future readers. While the person asking this question may understand your answer, explaining how you arrived at it could help countless others.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select * from (
select *,cast(AttDate as time) MyTime
from yourtable
)d
where d.MyTime!='00:00:00.000'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter out the instances where time is midnight, you can simply cast your date to `date` and compare if they are equal, like so:

```
select * from [Table] where [Date] <> convert(date, [Date])
```

Comment: @Stonz2 Was meaning to do that - got pulled into a meeting and wanted to get something down for the user